# Vue UI is not working through docker-compose

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose

I'm trying to get a docker ready VUE application setup and ready to go using the UI tool the vue framework supplies; (the command `vue ui` will start the UI which is then accessed via the web browser).

I was able to get a project setup successfully but only by using the command line method using vue create app-name-here and going through the prompts.  Below is an image of it working that way.

[image: vue default program working]

I wanted to use the VueUI so I could follow along on some learning tutorials regarding this and to explore it's features but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work.

As you can see in the images I uploaded below it says it's ready on port :8000 and the docker-compose file is indeed set to be open on the port 8000 and also confirmed via docker ps command as seen below.

[image: vue ui supposedly working?]

[image: docker proof of port open]

I can also verify that port 8000 is not being used by another process on my main computer (`lsof -i tcp:8000`).  This command just shows that only docker is using it as it should.

[image: proof not being used on same computer]

As you can see I have done everything in my power to ensure the port is open but when I go to the web browser to see the UI all I see is it can't be found, which is strange because the default project works just fine.

[image: clearly showing me going to same host just different port and vue ui not working]

**How can I get the Vue UI to work through docker** like this?

**NOTE**

I start the vue ui server after I run docker-compose by executing into the container like this.

```
docker exec -it front_end_node /bin/bash
```

from there I can simply run `vue ui`, which is what you see in the screenshots above.

**Docker-Compose File**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    dblive:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - ./db_data_live:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./database_config/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
            MYSQL_DATABASE: live
            MYSQL_USER: someadmin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: somepassword
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    dbdev:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - ./db_data_dev:/var/lib/mysql
            - ./database_config/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123456
            MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
            MYSQL_USER: someadmin
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
    phpmyadmin:
        depends_on:
            - dblive
            - dbdev
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
        environment:
            PMA_ARBITRARY : 1
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php:/etc/phpmyadmin/config.user.inc.php
        ports:
            - "8081:80"
    front_end_node:
        image: "poolservice/callcenter:1.0"
        container_name: front_end_node
        depends_on:
            - dblive
            - dbdev
        user: "node"
        working_dir: /home/node/app
        environment:
          #- NODE_ENV=production
          - NODE_ENV=development
        volumes:
          - ./app/call-center:/home/node/app
        ports:
          #Standard HTTP Dev Port
          - "8080:8080"
          #Vue UI Port
          - "8000:8000"
          #SSH Port
          - "443:443"
          # Tail command prints outputs from a process (either all or specified amount)
          #-F allows realtime streaming output of the changing file which is how it keeps it running so docker does not quit!
          #tail -F command here
        command: "/bin/sh -c 'cd call-center && npm run serve'"
```

**The Docker File**

```
# Use base image node 12
FROM node:12.9.1

# Set working directory in the container
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Install the loopback client so we have access to it's commands.
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli

# Expose port 3000,8080 and 8000
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8000
```

**New Things Recently Tried**

I got this to work on my normal host and noticed it was 8001 as the port, so I tried this port instead, still didn't work though.

When I executed into the container I tried `vue ui --port 8001` to ensure it was on that port and still no luck even after ensuring it was open.

I did notice that on my mac it **tries to load the browser up**.  In a docker container this is not possible.  It also tries to get access to the files, so I'm not sure if this has something to do with it not working or not.  I will be investigating further...

Comment: can you check `docker logs node_container_id`

Comment: yes, there is quite a bit there, but the very last few things are this.  DONE  Compiled successfully in 9856ms4:18:39 AM

<s> [webpack.Progress] 100%


  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/

  It seems you are running Vue CLI inside a container.
  Access the dev server via http://localhost:<your container's external mapped port>/

  Note that the development build is not optimized.
  To create a production build, run npm run build.

Comment: Did you try to expose port 8000 from your dockerfile ?

Comment: Yes, ports:
          #Standard HTTP Dev Port
          - "8080:8080"
          #Vue UI Port
          - "8000:8000" , I show this in the docker compose file, I also did it in the dockerfile itself though and didn't work.  Keep in mind that the Dockerfile expose doesn't matter since I have the original 8080 port working fine for the project created through the terminal method.  I only was exposing it via the docker-compose, but none the less I did try the dockerfile as well.  I can update to show that change.

Comment: If anyone can try recreating this, you just have to run docker-compose up after creating that docker image.  It's a very simplistic setup so should be easy to reproduce.  Let me know if anyone needs any help! This is a very strange error indeed.  I'm sure it's something simple I must be missing.  Plus I'm curious if anyone else can get this to work through docker?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured out what the issue was.  After typing vue ui --help I looked at a list of options.

```
vue ui --headless --port 8000 --host 0.0.0.0
```

I experimented with starting the command this way and discovered that you want to run in headless mode and in particular the host has to be 0.0.0.0.  By default it was localhost which does not work with docker!

I hope this helps someone else trying to use the UI in Docker!

Comment: Made my day, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Abdullah sure thing :), glad it helped.

Comment: `--host 0.0.0.0` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in package.json i was set this line and problem solved:

```
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --host 0.0.0.0",
```